# How to limit the number of item shown in <h:Selectonemenu>?

Tags: jsf

How can we limit the size of h:selectonemenu to show suppose 10 values. In our application we have a drop down which has more then 100 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's already not possible with plain HTML+CSS, so JSF can't do much for you here.

Best bet would be to mimic a dropdown yourself using `<div><ul><li>` and a good shot of CSS/JS.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem & solved through style tag,
In primefaces: height will do.try this one-

```
    <h:selectOneMenu style="width:150px;   />
```